# How to get the number of characters (as opposed to the number of bytes) of a text in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7, charactercount

I have a **Delphi 7** application where I deal with ANSI strings and I need to count their number of characters (as opposed to the number of bytes). I always know the Charset (and thus the code page) associated with the string.

So, knowing the Charset (code page), I'm currently using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the number of characters. It's useful when the Charset is one of the Chinese, Korean, or Japanese charsets where most of the characters are 2 bytes in length and simply using the `Length` function won't give me what I want.

However, it still counts **composite characters** as two characters, and I need them counted as one. Now, some composite characters have precomposed versions in Unicode, those would be counted correctly as one character since the `MB_PRECOMPOSED` is used by default. But many characters simply don't exist as precomposed, for example characters in Hebrew, Arabic, Thai, etc, and those are counted as two.

So the question really is: **How to count composite characters as single characters?** I don't mind converting the ANSI strings to Wide strings to count the number of characters, I'm already doing it with `MultiByteToWideChar` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the Unicode code points like this:

```
function CodePointCount(P: PWideChar): Integer;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  while Word(P^)<>0 do
  begin
    if (Word(P^)>=$D800) and (Word(P^)<=$DFFF) then
      // part of surrogate pair
      inc(Count)
    else 
      inc(Count, 2);
    inc(P);
  end;  
  Result := Count div 2;
end;
```

This covers the issue that you did not mention. Namely that UTF-16 is a variable width encoding.

However, this will not tell you the number of glyphs represented by a UTF-16 string. That's because some code points represent combining characters. These combining characters combine with their neighbours to form a single equivalent character. So, multiple code-points, single glyph. More information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

This is the harder issue. To solve it your code needs to fully understand the meaning of each Unicode code point. Is it a combining character? How does it combine? Really you  need a dedicated Unicode library. For instance ICU.

The other suggestion I have for you is to give up using ANSI code pages. If you really care about internationalisation then you need to use Unicode.

Comment: `MultiByteToWideChar` already covers the fact that UTF-16 is a variable-length encoding and returns the same result as your function. I was hoping there might be another api function that returns the actual number of glyphs, taking into consideration combining characters. Yeah, I know I have to migrate to Unicode, but that will take a lot of time, so I need temporary solutions until then. The question really becomes: **Is there a lightweight Unicode library that is compatible with Delphi 7 and has a straightforward function for getting the number of glyphs?** Perhaps the Soft Gems one?

Comment: Use ICU. And no, MultiByteToWideChar returns the number of code points.

Comment: Then I'm a little bit confused about `MultiByteToWideChar`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "If this value is 0, the function returns the required buffer size, in **characters**". And if I give it Chinese characters, they are counted correctly. What am I missing here?

Comment: I misspoke before. When I said code points I should have said character elements. That is the number of WideChar values. That's what MSDN means when it says characters.

Comment: Okay, I got it. The reason why it seems to me that your function doesn't return anything different than `MultiByteToWideChar` (and in my situation it really doesn't) is that I always feed it with ANSI strings (that's what the question is about), and they always fall in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) which always uses a single WideChar (Word, 2-bytes), never surrogate pairs. So I'm essentially using UCS-2, not UTF-16.